# regex: escaping \" /\\"/g Not Working

Tags: javascript, json, regex, string, object

I have a string that goes something like this:

```
/* ACTUAL DATA */

\n\nsampleArr[0] = {
    \n\t\tid: '28375023',
    \n\t\ttelephoneNumber: 5558378402,
    \n\t\tage: \" 4 \",
    \n\t\tmessageID: '287592',
    \n\t\tcommentID: '23845702',
    \n\t\tfoobar: 'foobar' \n\t
};
```

I am able to remove all \n\t\t using regex but just cannot deal with age section where it has \" 4 \".

```js
const input = String.raw`{
    name: 'foo',
    age: 12,
    address: \"1212 Mason st. \",
    zipcode: '12345',
    state: \"CA\"
 }`;

 console.log(input.replace(/\\"/g, "'"));
```

My main goal is to turn this into an object. However, the escaped characters \" are creating some major issues. I tried to use `str.replace(/\\"/g, "'")` and it seems like it is not matching nor replacing it. However, on https://regex101.com, it definitely is selecting all \" s.   Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure the string actually contains those characters? If I create a string that *does* look like that then your regex works: https://jsfiddle.net/jgkyvno4/ (Where does your string come from?)

Comment: @nnnnnn Where the string comes from isn't the issue. I am stuck with working around the other developers. I realize that it is not a valid string literal. However, when you replace \" s with ' would turn it into a valid string. 
Thus, why I am trying to use regex to make it into a valid String.

Comment: Assuming the line breaks in your sample data actually correspond to `\n` newlines, and the backslashes escaping the double quotation marks are physical backslashes, then your replacement should work, so something else must be going on. See revised snipped.

Comment: My point is I don't think your string contains what you think it does. How do you know what it contains, are you logging it to the console, or...?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the backslashes escaping the double quotation marks in your input are physical backslashes, then your replacement should work, so something else must be going on.

```js
const input = String.raw`{
    name: 'foo',
    age: 12,
    address: \"1212 Mason st. \",
    zipcode: '12345',
    state: \"CA\"
 }`;

 console.log(input.replace(/\\"/g, "'"));
```

In the above, we use [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to specify multi-line input, and `String.raw` to avoid interpreting the `\"` escapes (just as a handy way of providing the input string).

Note that this will fail if the strings themselves contain escaped quotation marks, as in

```
address: \"685 9th \"A\" Main Rd.\",
```

The ultimate solution is to have the back-end or whoever is producing these strings not escape the double quotation marks unless they occur **within** the strings. In other words, produce proper JSON.